# What is the command I say to make the curser 'Return' while in Notes using dictation?

Tags: notes.app, voice-dictation

What is the command I can say when I am using dictation in Notes that is the same as pressing the Return key? For example if I want to make a list or just create a new line for a new sentence?

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out its. New Line

Comment: Obvious once you know !